# Join tables based on matching criteria and Subtract the sum of Table2.Quantity from sum of Table1.Quantity for matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I am using the code below:
table1-add, table2-remove

```
SELECT add.description, add.size, (sum(add.qty) - sum(remove.qty)) AS OnHand
`FROM add LEFT JOIN remove ON (add.description = remove.description) AND `(add.size = remove.size) 
group by add.description, add.size
OnHand FROM add RIGHT JOIN remove ON (add.description = remove.description) AND 
(add.size = remove.size) WHERE add.description IS NULL and add.size is null 
group by add.description, add.size;
```

My objective is expressed in the title.

I have tried a few other approaches but it doesn't sum the columns before subtraction. It subtracts the first matching entry only.

Other approaches:

```
SELECT add.description, add.size, sum(add.qty) - sum(remove.qty) AS OnHand
FROM add INNER JOIN remove 
ON add.description = remove.description
WHERE add.size = remove.size
GROUP BY add.description, add.size;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to do the groups first, to calculate the sum of each table - then do the subtract;

```
SELECT t1.description, t1.size, (sum_add - sum_rem) AS OnHand
FROM 
( SELECT add.description, add.size, sum(add.qty) as sum_add from add GROUP BY add.description, add.size )t1 
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT remove.description, remove.size, sum(remove.qty) as sum_rem from remove GROUP BY remove.description, remove.size )t2
ON t1.description = t2.description and t1.size = t2.size
```

Code is untested and can probably be done in a nicer way - but this should work.

Comment: Great! :) No problem. Feel free to accept the answer..! :)